# VC++ exception handling - app crashes anyway

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

Following is the code snippet I have written in the process of learning exception handling in C++(using visual studio 2010 compiler).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void multi_double() {

double first,second,product;
try{
cout << "Enter the first number\n";
cin >> first;
cout << "Enter the second number\n";
cin >> second;
product = first * second;
cout << product;
}
catch(...){cout << "Got an exceptional behaviour";}

}
void stud_age(){
int age;
try{
cout << "Enter student's age\n";
cin >> age;
if(age < 0)
    throw;
cout << endl <<age;
}
catch(...) {
    cout << "Caught here\n";
}
}
class Model{
public:
Model(){cout << "ctor\n";}
~Model(){cout << "dtor\n";}
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
//multi_double();
//stud_age();
int a;
try{
    Model obj;
    int *p = NULL;
    *p = 0;//expecting access violation exception

}
catch(...){
    cout << "caught an exception\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Enable C++ exception is set to Yes[/EHsc].
But when I run the application,it is still crashing anyway ! with following information:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: DataTypeConversions.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4ffd8c3d
  Fault Module Name:    DataTypeConversions.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ffd8c3d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00001051

Why is not control coming to catch block?!

Comment: You need to compile with /EHa to have catch(...) also catch processor exceptions.  Which is a Really Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2):

Access Violations and all other kinds of hardware exceptions are handled in Windows using a mechanism called "C Structured Exception Handling (SEH)". This was originally designed to give C programs a more "structured" way to handle exceptions than the usual signal()/sigaction() mechanism in Posix based systems.

SEH exceptions *can* be integrated into the C++ Exception system, by setting a translator function which is called before SEH stack unwinding takes place. The new translator function simply throws a  C++ exception and, presto, C++ can catch the error!

See this Document from the MSDN for all the details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5z4bw5h5(v=vs.80).aspx

And here's a working example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <eh.h>
// You need to enable the /EHa excpetion model to make this work.
// Go to 
// Project|Properties|C/C++|Code Generation|Enable C++ Exceptions
// and select "Yes with SEH Exceptions (/EHa)"

void trans_func( unsigned int u, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExp )
{
    // printf( "In trans_func.\n" );
    throw "Hardware exception encountered";
}

int main() 
{
    _set_se_translator(trans_func);
    try
    {
        int *p = NULL;
        *p = 0;//expecting access violation exception
    }
    catch(const char *s)
    {
        std::cout << "caught an exception:" << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C++ exception handling system can not hardware-generated (ie. access violation etc) exceptions, only exceptions generated by code through `throw exception;`.

If you want to catch these exceptions, it is only possible in Windows through the use of [structured exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This is not compatible with other compilers and uses the `__try` `__except` construct rather than normal `try` / `catch`.

Comment: SEH exceptions and C++ exceptions can be fused together, see my answer.