# What happens if there's an error on while loop check

Tags: c++, error-handling, while-loop

I have a section of code:

```
HANDLE  hProcess;
DWORD   dwExitCode;
DWORD   dwDelay;

while (GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &dwExitCode))
{
    if (STILL_ACTIVE == dwExitCode)
    {
        Sleep(dwDelay);
    }
    else
    {
        strMsg.Format("Process completed with exit code %d", dwExitCode);
        LogComment(strMsg);
        return;
    }
}
dwExitCode = GetLastError();
strMsg.Format("Error %d getting exit code.", dwExitCode);
LogComment(strMsg)
```

Will this work?  My question is basically, if there's an error making the function call to get an expression for the `while` loop, will it just bounce out of that loop and let me catch the error?  Or do I need to set up something like a `try...catch` block for this?

Comment: What should `%dwExitCode` mean? Does your code even compile??

Comment: I added variable declarations to clarify. `dwExitCode` is a `DWORD`.

Comment: I specifically referred to the `%`, did you mean `&`?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo.  It's correct in my actual code.

Comment: What do you mean by "error"? A C++ exception (throw std::runtime_error)? A crash, such as a null-pointer access? Or do you mean "if GetExitCodeProcess() returns something bad"

Your loop will only exit if GetExitCodeProcess() returns 0 (which it will do in the case of the errors listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) or dwExitCode is not STILL_ACTIVE in which case it will return out of the function.

Comment: The first two. I wrote my code to handle returning 0, where the function call failed, but I was concerned about other issues not getting logged.

Comment: To catch cases like null pointer, divide by zero, etc, etc, you'll need to write a crash handler, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434817/vc-exception-handling-app-crashes-anyway

Another thing you can do is replace your main with a `try { innerMain(); } catch ...` to catch any C++ runtime exceptions. Otherwise the above code is only going to catch conditions where GetExitCodeProcess returns a zero such as the process going away or not existing, I would assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by error you mean exception, then yes if you don't put it in a `try/catch` block it'll bounce out of there.

Comment: Okay, yes, that's what I meant.  I was just wondering if having it inside the `while` loop's expression to check against would alter the scope for error or exception handling in a way such that being bounced would just bounce it out of the loop to the next level up of code, where I could catch it "automatically" in the next line.

Comment: @JoeMajsterski no, it will bounce immediately out of the enclosing function.  There's no executing any *next* lines.

Answer (score 1):

According to GetExitCodeProcess on MSDN

```
Return value
If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
```

If this function returns 0, i.e specifically the GetExitCodeProcess() call fails somehow, then yes, your loop will terminate.

```
while (GetExitCodeProcess())
```

means

```
while (GetExitCodeProcess() == true)
```

or
    while (GetExitCodeProcess() != 0)

[these two statements are equivalent; zero is false, non-zero is true]

which is equivalent to:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
    auto gecpResult = GetExitCodeProcess(...);
    if (gecpResult == 0)
        break;
```

Comment: Yes, that was the situation I was coding for originally, but I was worried about other failures and whether or not they would be caught at all with the code as written.

Comment: Nope, nothing in the sample code is going to protect you against, e.g., `char* p = NULL; *p = 0;` inside the loop. For that, you'll want to look into some form of crash handler. Take a look at [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And if you are trying to be thorough, you may want signal handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx